# What's a more professional term than 'blow your mind'?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that describes the experience of limits, preconceptions and world-views being challenged, exceeded and revised. I convey this if I say something "blew my mind", but there is a casual and left-field tone that I'd like to avoid.

What's a more sober and professional way to describe this experience? The intonations of personal transformation and the revision of self-boundaries are important elements that I'm looking to include.

Comment: I know you're looking for a **more** professional phrase, but my favorite variant of this is "blow your _tiny_ mind."

Comment: That experience **took my breath away**

Comment: OK, I'm commenting on an old question. But I'm surprised that no-one has mentioned 'epiphany' which apart from its religious meaning, also has a secular meaning that seems to fit completely.

Answer (score 11):

Made me think about X in a whole new way.
Gave me a new perspective.
Stunned / amazed / astonished me.

Comment: Really like your first two, thanks. They convey that the experience was transformational.

Answer (score 7):

These can't be used in an exclamatory way like *blew my mind*, but I think they might give the basic sense that you're looking for?

- expand one's horizons
- push the envelope
- changed my perspective / worldview
- take x to a new level
- a paradigm shift

And my personal favorite:

- is deserving of a fat end-of-year bonus

:-)

Answer (score 6):

[Blown away](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow+away), in the 3rd sense listed of "amaze" or "astound", is probably more formal-sounding that "blew my mind". For example:

> I was blown away when that happened.

Or, have a look at synonyms for [surprise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/surprise). Try:

> That was a revelation.
>
> The experience filled me with wonder.

If the sense of otherworldliness is important, [transcendent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transcendent) may be appropriate, as in:

> That was a transcendent experience.

Comment: I really like "that was a revelation", it gives the sense of the experience being a watershed in one's personal history. This is a vital aspect of the phrase for me.

Comment: +1 I like revelation too. I think it's perfect to describe a shift in your mindset or way of thinking that affects your whole life.  Like a paradigm shift, only on a personal level.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I personally would use to express "mind = blown" in a sober and professional way:

> The experience opened my eyes to ... [X]

where [X] might be "a whole new way of looking at the world" or some other expression indicating the domain in which the epiphany happened. Speaking of which, **epiphany** is a good word itself to describe that state. It means

> a moment of sudden revelation or insight. [NOAD]

This is a synonym for the Buddhist term *satori*, which means "sudden enlightenment" (from the Japanese [悟り](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/japkanji.php?d1=on&s=%E6%82%9F%E3%82%8A&btnS=!&max=10&exact=on&d3=on&d9=on&d15=on)).

Answer (score 3):

A few more: "Sth. **blew my mind**" could also be expressed as follows:

- It utterly **shocked** me.
- I was **flabbergasted**.
- I was **dumbfounded** (this one might more aptly convey the sense of *"personal transformation and the revision of self-boundaries"*).
- I was **in awe of** ...

Answer (score 2):

I'd submit: "*Astound*". E.g. "The speech really astounded me."

Answer (score 2):

I would say - ***"By George, that was something"***

Comment: Haha! Love that expression

Comment: It doesn't actually fit the register.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an answer in a real sober mood without the use of any flowery language or superlative tense, I would put it like -

> That was completely unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

It was a "paradigm-shifting" experience. See [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more professional one:

> Swept me off my feet

Comment: This seems to convey a sense of exhilaration but not of boundaries being revised and exceeded - there is a transformative element to 'blew my mind' that I'd like to retain.

Comment: (1) This doesn't sound any more professional; (2) I almost always see this with the connotation of seduction/love at first sight, i.e. entirely the wrong meaning.

Answer (score -2):

I like "my gray matter exponentially increased".

Comment: That misuses *exponentially*.

Comment: I suppose you can use humor in the workplace, but the requested context sounds more like professional writing.